# Android - Image Scattering in a Screen

Tags: android, animation

When a click on a button in a screen,i need images to get scattered in the screen (like stars scattering fo full screen) but need the images to scatter from bottom to top.
I think it is possible using animation, but i could not find solution.can anyone help me in  this.

Comment: there are lots of examples available.. just google it.

Comment: thanks for ur response...i m trying but still i could not find it

Comment: check below my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this bottom_up.xml in xml folder under res folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <translate android:fromYDelta="75%p" android:toYDelta="0%p" 
    android:fillAfter="true"
 android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

and in Activity code:

```
Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
            R.anim.bottom_up);

yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        yourimageview.startanimation(bottomUp);
    }
});
```

Comment: i have mentioned that it has to scatter

Comment: you mean, you want to move continously bottom up, up bottom.??

Comment: yes, if have a star image, group of stars should scatter around the screen....and the scatter effect should start from bottom.thanks for your response